# búsqueda binaria

Tags: c

Saludos, actualmente estoy estudiando c en la universidad, me pidieron crear un árbol de búsqueda binaria que recibe un diccionario con palabras para traducir y un x numero de inputs que consisten en textos con palabras a traducir y devuelve texto con las palabras traducidas, el codigo compila, pero al tratar de ejecutarlo me arroja segmentation fault (core dumped) y no logro encontrar la causa, agradecería si alguien me puede indicar que puntero(asumo que es un puntero) esta mal, dejo el codigo aquí:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct nodoArbolBin{
char palabra[20];
char trad[20];
struct nodoArbolBin *izq;
struct nodoArbolBin *der;   
}nodoABB;

typedef struct arbolBinario{
nodoABB *raiz;
int nElem;
}ABB;

void initTree(ABB *T){
T->raiz = NULL;
T->nElem = 0;
}

void clearHelp(nodoABB *n){
if(n==NULL){
    return;}
clearHelp(n->izq);
clearHelp(n->der);
free((void*)n);

}
void clear(ABB *T){
clearHelp(T->raiz);
T->raiz = NULL;
T->nElem = 0;

}

char *findHelp(nodoABB *n, char *p){
if (n==NULL){
    return "NOT A WORD";
    }
if (strcmp(n->palabra,p)==0){
    return n->trad;
    }
if (strcmp(n->palabra,p)<0){
    return findHelp(n->izq,p);
    }
else{
    return findHelp(n->der,p);
    }
}

char *find(ABB *T, char *p){
return findHelp(T->raiz,p);

}


void insert(ABB *T, char *p1, char *p2){
nodoABB *temp, *nuevo;
int flag = 0;   

temp = T->raiz;
while(flag == 0){
    if(temp == NULL){
        strcpy(nuevo->palabra, p1);
        strcpy(nuevo->trad, p2);
        nuevo->izq = NULL;
        nuevo->der = NULL;
        T->raiz = nuevo;
        flag = 1;
        }
    if(strcmp(p1,temp->palabra)<0 && temp->izq != NULL){
        temp = temp->izq;
        }
    if(strcmp(p1,temp->palabra)<0 && temp->izq == NULL){
        strcpy(nuevo->palabra, p1);
        strcpy(nuevo->trad, p2);
        nuevo->izq = NULL;
        nuevo->der = NULL;
        nuevo = temp->izq;
        flag = 1;
        }
    if(strcmp(p1,temp->palabra)>0 && temp->der != NULL){
        temp = temp->der;
        }
    if(strcmp(p1,temp->palabra)>0 && temp->der == NULL){
        strcpy(nuevo->palabra, p1);
        strcpy(nuevo->trad, p2);
        nuevo->izq = NULL;
        nuevo->der = NULL;
        nuevo = temp->der;
        flag = 1;
        }

}
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
FILE *fp1,*fp2;
char pal[20];
char tras[20];
char out[10];
char n[10]; 
char trad[10];
char retorno[20];
char ou[6] = "output";
int i,ni;
ABB *arbol;

initTree(arbol);
fp1 = fopen(argv[1],"r");
while(!feof(fp1)){
    fscanf(fp1,"%s",pal);
    fscanf(fp1,"%s",tras);
    insert(arbol,pal,tras);
    }
fclose(fp1);
ni = argc;
for(i=2;i<ni;i++){
    fp1 =fopen(argv[i],"r");
    strcpy(out,ou);
    sprintf(n,"%d",i-2);
    strcat(out,n);
    fp2 =fopen(out,"w");
    while(!feof(fp1)){
        fscanf(fp1,"%s",trad);
        strcpy(retorno,find(arbol,trad));
        fprintf(fp2,"%s\n",retorno);
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
}
clear(arbol);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para sobrevivir en este mundo te recomiendo que aprendas a usar el depurador de código. Al principio puede ser un poco confuso, pero piensa que es una herramienta imprescindible.

```
void insert(ABB *T, char *p1, char *p2){
  nodoABB *temp, *nuevo; // <<--- 1
  int flag = 0;   

  temp = T->raiz;
  while(flag == 0){
    if(temp == NULL){
        strcpy(nuevo->palabra, p1); // <<--- 2
```

1. Declaras un puntero, como no lo inicializas apunta a una posición de memoria aleatoria
2. Almacenas valores en la posición aleatoria del punto 1. Lo más probable es que esa memoria pertenezca a otro proceso... el Sistema Operativo lo detecta y mata tu proceso para evitar que corrompa la memoria.

Lo que tienes que hacer es reservar memoria antes de usar los punteros. Par esta tarea puedes usar `malloc` o `calloc`. Como los nodos tienen punteros y los mismos, en los nuevos nodos, van a apuntar a `NULL` al no tener hijos todavía, yo elegiría `calloc`, que inicializa todos los bytes a 0.

Y también optaría por reducir la vida de las variables al mínimo (el requisito que obligaba a declarar las variables al inicio de la función es anterior al estándar  C99, que data de 1999... no te digo más).

Para simplificar un poco más el hilo de ejecución yo optaría por comprobar, fuera del bucle, si el árbol está vacío:

```
void insert(ABB *T, char *p1, char *p2)
{
  nodoABB* nuevo = (nodoABB*)calloc(1,sizeof(nodoABB));
  strcpy(nuevo->palabra, p1);
  strcpy(nuevo->trad, p2);

  if( T->raiz == NULL )
  {
    T->raiz = nuevo;
    return;
  }

  nodoABB* temp = T->raiz;
  while( 1 )
  {
    if(strcmp(p1,temp->palabra)<0)
    {
      if( temp->izq == NULL )
      {
        temp->izq = nuevo;
        break;
      }

      temp = temp->izq;
    }
    else if(strcmp(p1,temp->palabra)>0)
    {
      if( temp->der== NULL )
      {
        temp->der= nuevo;
        break;
      }

      temp = temp->der;
    }
    else
    {
      // p1 == temp->palabra... ¿Que hacemos aqui?
    }
  }
}
```